# Getting undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on building a little app that accepts input from a form (the input being a name) and then goes on to POST the name to a mock webservice using $httpBackend. After the POST I then do a GET also from a mock webservice using $httpBackend that then gets the name/variable that was set with the POST. After getting it from the service a simple greeting is constructed and displayed back at the client.

However, currently when the data gets displayed now back to the client it reads "Hello undefined!" When it should be reading "Hello [whatever name you inputed] !". I used Yeoman to do my app scaffolding so I hope everyone will be able to understand my file and directory structure.

My app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('sayHiApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMockE2E',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
  .run(function($httpBackend) {

    var name = 'Default Name';

    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/name').respond(function(method, url, data) {

      //name = angular.fromJson(data);
      name = data;

      return [200, name, {}];
    });

    $httpBackend.whenGET('/name').respond(name);

    // Tell httpBackend to ignore GET requests to our templates
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough();

  });
```

My main.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sayHiApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    // Accepts form input
    $scope.submit = function() {

      // POSTS data to webservice
      setName($scope.input);

      // GET data from webservice
      var name = getName();

      // Construct greeting
      $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + name + ' !';

    };

    function setName (dataToPost) {

      $http.post('/name', dataToPost).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.error = false;
        return data;
      }).
      error(function(data) {

        $scope.error = true;
        return data;
      });
    }

    // GET name from webservice
    function getName () {

      $http.get('/name').
      success(function(data) {

        $scope.error = false;
        return data;
      }).
      error(function(data) {

        $scope.error = true;
        return data;
      });

    }

  });
```

My main.html:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <img src="../images/SayHi.png" class="logo" />

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

        <form role="form" name="greeting-form" ng-Submit="submit()">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-field" name="name-field" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="input">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default button">Greet Me!</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <p class="greeting">{{greeting}}</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: function getName () -> This should be a bona fide AngularJS service, with dependency injection. Right now everything is your controller, which is a bad bad bad idea in ANgular's world.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to Angular and I'm not sure what you mean by "bona fide" ? Are you saying I should just extract the 'setName' and 'getName' functions into another separate file?

Comment: Google is your friend :-) http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bona+fide AngularJS services are singletons, and are better suited for anything CRUD. [http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2013/09/angularjs-service-vs-factory-with-example/](http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2013/09/angularjs-service-vs-factory-with-example/) - a separate file if you wish. The main thing being to explicit create/declare a service, which you import with DI into your controller. Create/interface_your_API in your service, code any CRUD function you need, and return it. Your promise could be in the service (best) or the controller.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your `getName()` method returns nothing. Also you cant just call `getName()` and expect the result to be available immediately after the function call since `$http.get()` runs asynchronously.
You should try something like this:

```
function getName () {
  //return the Promise
  return $http.get('/name').success(function(data) {
    $scope.error = false;
    return data;
  }).error(function(data) {
    $scope.error = true;
    return data;
  });
}

$scope.submit = function() {
  setName($scope.input);
  //wait for the Promise to be resolved and then update the view
  getName().then(function(name) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + name + ' !';
  });
};
```

By the way you should put `getName(), setName()` into a service.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and helping me :) What it's returning now though is [Object Object]

Comment: I dont know what exactly your service returns. You could just log `data` to the console in your success handler to see what comes back and transform the result accordingly (extract the name). You can read more about it in the documentation of $http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a regular variable from an async call because by the time this success block is excuted the function already finished it's iteration. 
You need to return a promise object (as a guide line, and preffered do it from a service).

I won't fix your code but I'll share the necessary tool with you - Promises.

Following angular's doc for [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you can build yourself a template for async calls handling.

The template should be something like that:

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('MyAsyncService', function($q, http) {

var service = {
    getNames: function() {
        var params ={};
        var deferObject = $q.defer();
        params.nameId = 1;
        $http.get('/names', params).success(function(data) {
            deferObject.resolve(data)
        }).error(function(error) {
            deferObject.reject(error)
        });

        return $q.promise;
    }
}
});

angular.module('mymodule').controller('MyGettingNameCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyAsyncService', function ($scope, MyAsyncService) {

    $scope.getName = function() {
        MyAsyncService.getName().then(function(data) {
            //do something with name
        }, function(error) {
            //Error 
        })
    }
}]);
```